# Setting default arguments to `...`

Tags: r

I have a function where I'm passing `...` to `plot`, so the user can add additional arguments. For some of these optional arguments, I'd like to setup default values, without declaring them as formal arguments in the function. Here's a simple example

```
simpleFun <- function(a, b,...) {
    args <- as.list(match.call())
    if(is.null(args$xlim)) args$xlim <- quote(c(-6, 6))

    plot(a, b, xlim = eval(args$xlim))
}
```

Then I can run `simpleFun(rnorm(10), rnorm(10), xlim = c(-1, 1))` or `simpleFun(rnorm(10), rnorm(10))` and `xlim` will be `c(-1, 1)` in the first example (defined by user) and `c(-6, 6)` in the second (not defined by user). The problem, of course, is that `...` is now not going anywhere. I'd like to specify it more like

```
simpleFun2 <- function(a, b,...) {
    args <- as.list(match.call())
    if(is.null(args$xlim)) args$xlim <- quote(c(-6, 6))

    plot(a, b, xlim = eval(args$xlim), ...)
}
```

so that any additional argument can be passed to `plot`, but then calling `simpleFun(rnorm(10), rnorm(10), xlim = c(-1, 1))` won't work because there will be two `xlim` arguments supplied to `plot`.

So, basically, I'm wondering if there's a way to set default values for any arguments passed through `...`? I realize the way I've defined things above is probably less than ideal, but it's the best I've come up with at this point (which still doesn't work).

Comment: @RichardScriven And ideally specify `envir = parent.frame()` to ensure that it’s evaluated where the user called the function.

Comment: @RichardScriven I like the thought, but it doesn't seem to work for me. If I replace `plot(a, b, xlim = eval(args$xlim), ...)` with `do.call("plot", c(args, ...))` I get `Error in plot(x, a = x, xlim = c(-6, 6)) : object 'x' not found` (along with an additional warning). Note that I get the same error when including `envir = parent.frame()`.

Comment: Hmm... When I run `simpleFun2(rnorm(10), rnorm(10))` (using your code) the limits of the x-axis end up `c(-1, 1.5)`, rather than the `c(-6, 6)` it should default to.

Comment: Ohhh, you have to change the names to `x` and `y`, silly me.  Try this one! `simpleFun2 <- function(a, b, ...) {  args <- as.list(match.call()[-1]);
  if(!any(names(args) == "xlim")) args$xlim <- c(-6, 6); names(args)[1:2] <- c("x", "y");  do.call(plot, args) }`

Comment: That's it! Perfect! Thanks so much!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have these arguments as formals with defaults since, one way or the other, some manipulation/checking inside `simpleFun` will be needed upon input? And also, as Frank comments, keep up with how R matches formal arguments.

Comment: You certainly could, and generally I agree that's probably the better course. In the actual case I was working with, the function already had a bunch of formals, and I didn't want to add more. Also, there are multiple functions within the primary function, and the specific function that is executed depends on one of the formals in the primary function.  I didn't want to actually set defaults for all the functions in the primary function, I only wanted to set defaults for a few of those subsumed within the primary function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this one calls for `do.call()`.  Notice I have renamed your default arguments `x` and `y` to match those for arguments 1 and 2 in `plot()`. If you want to continue to use `a` and `b`, uncomment the fourth line.  But it will make things a lot easier if you stick with the default names.

```
simpleFun <- function(x, y, ...) {
    args <- as.list(match.call()[-1])
    if(!any(names(args) == "xlim")) 
        args$xlim <- c(-6, 6)
    ## names(args)[1:2] <- c("x", "y")
    do.call("plot", args)
}
```

This seems to work fine on these sample runs.

```
simpleFun2(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10))
simpleFun2(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10), xlim = c(-1, 1))
simpleFun2(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10), xlim = c(-1, 1), ylim = c(-4, 4))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Unlike most args, I guess this must be written out in full. I can write `plot(rnorm(10), rnorm(10), xli=c(-6,6))` but not `simpleFun(rnorm(10), rnorm(10), xli=c(-6,6))`

Comment: Just in case it's helpful to others, I had to apply this to a density plot as well, and it's a little different there because ideally the function would require only one argument (the object to calculate the density on). In that case, I found the following to work well, which uses a slightly different method to create `args`.  

    `densPlotEx <- function(a, ...) {
 args <- list("x" = quote(density(a)), ...)

 if(is.null(args$xlim)) {
   args$xlim <- quote(c(-6, 6))
  }
 
 do.call(plot, args)
}`